# Using JavaScript to add TR+TD Content using one selection input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have one selection input with about 5 options in it. I also have one empty table that will use this format:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>X(for delete)</td>
      <td>Option name</td>
      <td>Value that is linked to that option name</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So what I want is this: when someone chooses a option from the select menu it has to make one new `<tr>` element in the table with 3 `<td>`. The first is just a "X" or image so that I can delete the `<tr>`, the second one is the option name and the third one a value that is linked to that option.

So how can I make a program that will add the TR for me and the TD's. The second part is: how can I make it so that when the user prewses the X it deletes the entire `<tr>` parent. And if possible how can I add all the values together from the 3 TD and display it on screen?

I know this is a lot but is there anyone here that can help me out?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't know if this is because of a copy and paste job for SO but you should try to keep `tr` in a `tbody,thead,tfoot`. Just because browsers will inject a `tbody` isn't a reason to trust it. Also what have you already tried?

Comment: To be honest I never used JS before so I was looking for some tuts on the web and on Lynda.com. This is just for a school project and not for a real job. So I am just looking for help here and in on the meanwhile watching video tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope it helps you in the right way:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('table').append('<tr><td class="remove">X</td><td class="optionValue">' + $('select option:selected').text() + '</td><td class="linkedValue">' + $('select').val() + '</td></tr>');
})

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Enter</button>
<br />
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>X(for delete)</td>
    <td>Option name</td>
    <td>Value that is linked to that option name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well thank you, didn't really know it was this easy to add content. This will help me out a lot thank you.

Comment: Nice, I have now added so the text from the select is shown in right td and the value from the select is show in the right td. If this answered you question please mark it as one.

Comment: Yes it deed and Yes I will.

Comment: There are allot of assumptions in this answer, first your assuming the browser will create a `tbody` which it currently does. Then your assuming jQuery will append your `tr` to the `tbody` and not directly to the `table`. I think making these assumptions without explaining them for someone stating they want to learn JS is not a good idea. Besides the fact your selectors would find every table on the page and every button but thats just me being pedantic.

Comment: You are right in what you are saying, but as I wrote on the top this is only a example in the right direction whit the same markup as the question. @ste2425

Comment: I changed the table and button to one class, I also fixed the tbody part. Thankyou for the help, the 2 of you.